# How Delete/remove row/rows from dataview (without using Dataview. Delete )

Tags: c#

How we delete The row from DataView 
i currently using

DataView DV = new DataView();

//populate

DV.Delete(5);

but for the dynamic rows we don't know  row index for any value in dataview
like i have 100 record in data view (rows)
where i want all record accept one value lets X(any value)
so how i delete it's specific value from Dataview or

any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to **hide** the rows, a [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) could solve your problem.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove them from the DataTable use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h71xaeh0.aspx) method of the DataTable and remove the DataRows that have been found.

Comment: Erno thank you but i not want to Hide  i just want to remove the row 
is that possible ?

Comment: @ertjain, So you want to delete them from the DataSet? the DataView is just a 'view'?

Comment: Erno thank you 

i try your suggestion  suggestion and guess what it's worked

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming `myRow` is of type `System.Data.DataRow` you can do:

```
int index = DV.Table.Rows.IndexOf(myRow);
DV.Delete(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sorted `DataView`:

`var dv = new DataView(dataTable, "id", null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);`

and then find row index

`var index = dv.Find(id);
if (index > -1)
    dv.Delete(index);`

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the DataRow, and then apply the delete.

```
DV.Row.Delete()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        // Create a command object. 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        // Assign the connection to the command. 
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        // Set the command text 
        // SQL statement or the name of the stored procedure  
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID";

        // Set the command type 
        // CommandType.Text for ordinary SQL statements;  
        // CommandType.StoredProcedure for stored procedures. 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Get the PersonID of the selected row. 
        string strProductID = gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;

        // Append the parameter. 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = strProductID;

        // Open the connection and execute the command. 
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Rebind the GridView control to show data after deleting. 
    BindGridView();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's best if answers provide a short explanation of what the code does in a paragraph, in addition to the comments in the code. Better answers make it more likely that people will give you upvotes, which will give you reputation. See [answer] for more information.