# How can I remove the values from the dataView?

Tags: c#, dataview

I want to remove the values that I have printed in the dataView.

```
dataView1.Rows.Clear();
```

When I try to put other values it prints me **"index out of value"** exception.

I want to put some other values I have selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Delete/remove row/rows from dataview (without using Dataview. Delete )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929184/how-delete-remove-row-rows-from-dataview-without-using-dataview-delete)

Comment: _When i try to put other values_ Show the code!

Comment: @taktak this is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
dataView1.Rows.Clear();
dataView1.Columns.Clear(); 
dataView1.Dispose();
```

Comment: I need to remove all the values!

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that :

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dataView1)
{
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;
    row.Delete();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specified the row. Instead `dataView1.Rows.Clear();` try this `dataView1.Rows[1].Clear();`